# Получить типы и имена полей таблицы в SQL DB

Tags: sql

Есть ли какой то способ получить типы и имена полей в таблице "кросс-базово", т.е. чтобы один метод работал на всех основных SQL базах, просто я столкнулся с тем что способ из MySQL не cработал на PgSQL.
Или универсального решения нет и надо под каждую БД пилить свой запрос.

Comment: Есть такая книга: SQL Cookbook, Anthony Molinaro. В ней приведены примеры запросов для _разных_ СУБД: DB2, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sql Server, MySql. Глава 5 Metadata Queries. Некоторые запросы совпадают, но в целом различаются, увы.

Comment: Эта книга есть на русском: SQL Сборник рецептов.

Comment: Понятно, я надеялся может гуру SQL знают какой-то секрет, но видимо секрета нет. Понятно, значит надо пилить под каждую базу свой запрос.